# Turn off Postgres parallel query for a single Django query

Tags: django, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a query that I need within my Django app that I needed to hand-optimize.  But getting the query to run fast means that I need to be able to tell Postgres "don't use parallelism on this".

What I thought would work was:

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()

# start a transaction so that PGBouncer runs the next statements
# on the same connection
cursor.execute("begin")

# turn off parallelism for this next query
cursor.execute("set max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0")

# run my query
cursor.execute("HAND-TUNED SELECT QUERY GOES HERE")

# process the cursor results

# Put this connection back in the PGBouncer pool, and reset 
# max_parallel_workers_per_gather.
cursor.execute("rollback")
```

But it does not seem to be working.  My query continues to show up in my "slow query" logs when I run it through the Django site, and the performance remains lousy (4+ seconds with parallelism, 0.5 seconds without).

Is there a way to do what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `SET LOCAL` so that the effect is limited to the transaction.

Then I recommend that you use [`auto_explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) to find out the actual plan that was used for the query. Maybe there is a different reason for the slowdown.